# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7b6f2de8a3e0> using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow

I face the following issue training my tensorflow model. I have checked my image files, there are no issues. I am using both .jpg and .png for my training data.

```
Epoch 1/80
20/20 [==============================] - 161s 7s/step - loss: 2.2676 - accuracy: 0.2350 - val_loss: 30.2687 - val_accuracy: 0.3500
Epoch 2/80
20/20 [==============================] - 135s 7s/step - loss: 1.7653 - accuracy: 0.3000 - val_loss: 21.5805 - val_accuracy: 0.3000
Epoch 3/80
20/20 [==============================] - 132s 7s/step - loss: 1.6071 - accuracy: 0.4000 - val_loss: 57.1780 - val_accuracy: 0.0500
Epoch 4/80
13/20 [==================>...........] - ETA: 41s - loss: 1.6615 - accuracy: 0.3750
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3e3e29e36d22> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 # Train the model
----> 5 history = model.fit(
      6       train_generator,
      7       steps_per_epoch=20, #400 images = batch_size * step 400= 10

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51   try:
     52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7b6f2de8a3e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 268, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py", line 917, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1064, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/preprocessing/image.py", line 116, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/preprocessing/image.py", line 370, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    img = image_utils.load_img(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/image_utils.py", line 423, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3283, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7b6f2de8a3e0>


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_20943]
```